# Deployment Server Ignores .htaccess File

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-deployment

My `.htaccess` file on root looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^en/users/profile/?$ [F,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/users/profile/?([0-9]+)?/?$ en/user/index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^en/users/profile/([0-9]+)/photo/? en/user/index.php?pageID=photoEdit&id=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example\.ge/?.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example\.dev/?.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost/?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

It can reroute perfectly on local host but it is ignored on deployment server! This is the 
[phpinfo();](http://merchantmarine.ge/test.php) of the server!

this is the etc folder:
[image: etc folder]

Comment: From your `phpinfo()` output it appears that deployment environment is running `LiteSpeed` web server not Apache. You may want to look at this link: https://www.internetearnings.com/how-to-check-mod_rewrite-module-in-apache-litespeed-is-loaded/

Comment: Your first `RewriteRule` directive is missing a _substitution_ and will not work as intended - you'll get an error if requesting `/en/users/profile/`. But you've not actually stated the URLs you are routing.

Comment: That is correct. Please provide an answer so I can accept it. Dear MrWhite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^en/users/profile/?$ [F,NC]
> ```

Not the cause of why your `.htaccess` file is being ignored (the other answers have already given solutions for that, with regards to checking the `AllowOverride` directive in the server config), but you are missing a valid *substitution* in the above directive. A request for `/en/users/profile/` will not be *forbidden* and will likely just result in an error/404.

It would need to be something like:

```
 RewriteRule ^en/users/profile/?$ - [F,NC]
```

(Just a single hyphen for the *substitution*.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example\.ge/?.*$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example\.dev/?.*$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost/?.*$ [NC]
> RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
> ```

You should also move your "hotlink protection" directives (above) to *before* your routing directives. Otherwise, it's possible (depending on the URL format) that the URL is routed *before* the hotlink protection is able to block the request.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't have `.htaccess` files enabled on the server. Have a look at the [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive. You can add something like this to the `<Directory>` block for your `<VirtualHost>`'s document root:

```
AllowOverride all
```

Comment: It's the main configuration for your Apache server, so it depends on your server and how it is managed. You could ask the host or tell me what your server setup is.

Comment: well the host is bought for us  in another country by someone else. and the support portal is all in georgi and I don't understand it. and my contact knows nothing about website stuff and the buyer cant speak in english :(!!!

Comment: Well this is an issue you're going to need to resolve! Best of luck.

Comment: You want me to help with the fact that you are unable to make any changes to your server, when resolving this involves making changes to your server?????? I already helped you and told you what to do, figuring out how to do it in the circumstances you have is not for anyone here to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146364/discussion-between-amin-bakhtiari-far-and-superduperapps).

Comment: well at least tell me what to look for in cpanel!!

Comment: This is free help, you are rude and unappreciative. I have already given you advice which you could attempt to understand on your own with Google. This conversation is at an end.

Comment: oh I'm so sorry. I did not meant to be rude. please accept my apologize! may be it's because my English is not very well! truly sorry!

Comment: Apology accepted. I'm not sure where to find it in cPanel, but if you Google for "cpanel allowoverride" I'm sure you'll find the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot dear friend! and sorry for inconvenient!

Comment: No worries, thanks. Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer which gives me some reputation for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit your virtual host:**

**1.** Login to your server.

**2.** cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/

**3.** You can edit your **default** or **web1** or ... virtual-host-**.conf**-file. Type **nano web1.conf** (...) and edit your file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yoururl.com      
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/web1/htdocs/
    <Directory /var/www/web1/htdocs/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

**4.** Stop your Apache2 and restart it - /etc/init.d/apache2 stop and /etc/init.d/apache2 start.

**5.** Upload your **.htaccess** into your root directory and test it.

If you using **Cloudflare**, then there is a option in the settings "**Always use HTTPS**" in the **SSL settings**. You can also use **Forwarding URL action**:

```
http://yoururl.fqdn/*
redirected with a 301 response code to
https://www.yoururl.fqdn/$1
```

Comment: Thx. But it is a shared server.

Comment: I have updated the question with a link to etc folder preview.

Comment: So, you have no access via SSH? You can't connected your Server via PuTTY or something like that?

Comment: Noap! Have no access through ssh.

Comment: Can you upload the htaccess once to your webspace, where the HTML pages stored?